# Spring oauth jwt browser works while curl fails

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth, jwt

I have followed this blog for spring oauth jwt: https://medium.com/@nydiarra/secure-a-spring-boot-rest-api-with-json-web-token-reference-to-angular-integration-e57a25806c50

In a browser like Chrome or IE edge, when I go to https://infinite-tundra-6984.herokuapp.com/springjwt/cities, I am prompted to enter username and password.

For standard user:

username: john.doe

password: jwtpass

For Admin:

username: admin.admin

password: jwtpass

It works as expected.

However, when I use curl:

curl testjwtclientid:MaYzkSjmkzPC57L@infinite-tundra-6984.herokuapp.com/oauth/token -d grant_type=password -d username=admin.admin -d password=jwtpass

I get a token like:
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJhdWQiOlsidGVzdGp3dHJlc291cmNlaWQiXSwidXNlcl9uYW1lIjoiYWRtaW4uYWRtaW4iLCJzY29wZSI6WyJyZWFkIiwid3JpdGUiXSwiZXhwIjoxNTA4MTMxNzQwLCJhdXRob3JpdGllcyI6WyJTVEFOREFSRF9VU0VSIiwiQURNSU5fVVNFUiJdLCJqdGkiOiIyNjVmYmY5OS0wYWU3LTQ0MmQtOThjNy03ZTkxMmFhYWZlNWYiLCJjbGllbnRfaWQiOiJ0ZXN0and0Y2xpZW50aWQifQ.exXHqinGAfoPYLFYxhiWIsEg1FSSHxw34Snxdk0AqnU

Then I do:

curl https://infinite-tundra-6984.herokuapp.com/springjwt/cities -H "Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJhdWQiOlsidGVzdGp3dHJlc291cmNlaWQiXSwidXNlcl9uYW1lIjoiYWRtaW4uYWRtaW4iLCJzY29wZSI6WyJyZWFkIiwid3JpdGUiXSwiZXhwIjoxNTA4MTMxNzQwLCJhdXRob3JpdGllcyI6WyJTVEFOREFSRF9VU0VSIiwiQURNSU5fVVNFUiJdLCJqdGkiOiIyNjVmYmY5OS0wYWU3LTQ0MmQtOThjNy03ZTkxMmFhYWZlNWYiLCJjbGllbnRfaWQiOiJ0ZXN0and0Y2xpZW50aWQifQ.exXHqinGAfoPYLFYxhiWIsEg1FSSHxw34Snxdk0AqnU"

I get a 401

Can someone give me some hints on the differences between the two ways of accessing secured content?

It seems like, with the curl/token access, it can't figure out my role

Answer (score 0):

I missed this step.

In application.properties, I need to add this line:

`security.oauth2.resource.filter-order = 3`

This has caused me so much time